# Google sheets How to repeat a formula on every cell in a row

Tags: google-sheets

I want to repeat a formula sum(AC4:AN4) over every row below adjusting its sum to becom AC5,AC6 etc without copy+paste/dragging it to every row.

I have tried using arrayforumla but it keeps on repeating the sum of AC4:AN5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of SUM we could use the add (plus) operator, but the references should be set by columns.

For simplicity, assume that we want to calculate totals by row of the rows 1 to 5 from the columns A, B and C. The following formula will return the expected result:

```
=ArrayFormula(A1:A5+B1:B5+C1:C5)
```

Comment: thank you! I did not think of adding the numbers that way